# How do I have a tutorial interface on my android app?

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to have a feature on my app that shows the user around when they first launch the app. it would display a take a demo option that would go through the main parts of the app. (For example,an arrow would point to the compose button and say compose or it would show the user how to access the settings menu.). I have done some reasearch and I believe you use a preference, but I am not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) library to highlight the key features of my application. It is very clean and easy to use.